# Python For loop multiple returns

Tags: python, printing, return

I am supposed to write a function for one of my computer science classes in python. The function is supposed to take in a startValue and then increment it until numberOfValues is reached. This is my function so far:

```
def nextNValues(startValue, increment, numberOfValues):
   result = int(0)
   for i in range(0, numberOfValues):
      increase = i * increment
       result = startValue + increase
   return result
```

I call it by doing:

```
print(nextNValues(5,4,3))
```

The problem is that the output is only 13. How do I make it so it returns a number each time it increments. For example, 5, 9, 13? I have been having this problem with my previous functions but I have just been adding and removing things without much logic to get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: As your class has dealt neither with lists not with generators, are you sure you have to _return_ the values? Maybe your task is to just `print` the values inside of the function?

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect use case for [*generators*](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Long story short, just use `yield` instead of `return`:

```
def nextNValues(startValue, increment, numberOfValues):
  result = int(0)
  for i in range(0, numberOfValues):
    increase = i * increment
    result = startValue + increase
    yield result
```

The clients of your code can then use it either in a simple loop:

```
for value in nextNValues(...):
  print(value)
```

Or they can get a list if needed by converting it with `list`.
For example, if one needed to print the result:

```
print(list(nextNValues(...)))
```

Comment: That didn't work. It ended up doing this <generator object nextNValues at 0x1027ebd20>

Comment: That's because you tried printing it directly. I showed how to use it. If you want to print it, use a conversion to `list`.

Answer (score 1):

You should build up a list. Each time through the iteration, append the number to the list. Then, at the end, simply return the list.

Comment: We haven't really worked with lists yet. The assignment is to do it through just for loops.

Comment: There is *no way* to do this "just through for loops". You need some sort of container to hold multiple values, such as a list. The alternative is to use a generator, as Denis proposes, but that is *significantly* more advanced - if you haven't even done lists yet, generators are definitely not the expected answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def nextNValues(startValue, increment, numberOfValues):
    result = []
    for i in range(0, numberOfValues):
        increase = i * increment
        #result = startValue + increase
        result.append(startValue + increase)
    return result
```